# Postgres is value in column

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables A and B. B includes a column `binder` which contains integers. Now I want to search those rows of table A which are in placed in A.binder. The following statement does what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.binder=ANY(SELECT binder FROM B)
```

But I expected something like

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.binder=ANY(B.binder)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.binder IN array_agg(B.binder)
```

would work. Consider B.binder could contain duplicates. Therefor I cant simplify the statement by using inner join.

Comment: its too simple try this 
*SELECT a.binder FROM B b inner join A a ON a.binder = b.binder GROUP BY a.binder ORDER BY a.binder*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An INNER JOIN is still possible.

```
SELECT A.* FROM A INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT binder FROM B) AS C ON
A.binder = C.binder
```

Why doesn't ANY(B.binder) work? because ANY in this context expects a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get your integers from table B.

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.binder IN (
    SELECT binder FROM B
);
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to my statement `SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.binder=ANY(SELECT binder FROM B)` from the start post?